# Calculate seconds between two Date/times in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ format

Tags: c#

Is there a quick way (in C#) to calculate the number of seconds between two strings containing date/time in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ format.

For example:

```
string startTime = "2017-03-27T13:58:39Z";
string endTime = "2017-03-27T14:07:26Z";

int numSecs = calculateSecondsBetween(startTime, endTime);
```

Yes, I could create a function that parses all this, but I was hoping for something easier than that.

Comment: What do you mean by `quick way`?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse`, `-(DateTime, DateTime)` operator and `Interval.TotalSeconds` come to mind as handy tools for the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substract them and use `TimeSpan`'s `TotalSeconds` property

```
string startTime = "2017-03-27T13:58:39Z";
string endTime = "2017-03-27T14:07:26Z";

int numSecs = (int)(DateTime.Parse(endTime) - DateTime.Parse(startTime)).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 4):

Subtract the datetime and get the `TotalSeconds`:

```
string startTime = "2017-03-27T13:58:39Z";
string endTime = "2017-03-27T14:07:26Z";
DateTime startTimeDt = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);  
DateTime endTimeDt = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime);  
var diffInSeconds = (endTimeDt - startTimeDt).TotalSeconds;
Console.Write(diffInSeconds);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In fact, [77 seconds too late](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43064880/timeline) ;)

Comment: I used my answer to calculate that you are 77 seconds to late

Comment: Did you use the datediff solution? Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

fubo and mindOfAi got there much faster than me, but if you're after something that's convenient and quick to put in your code you could create an extension method to make it cleaner:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static int NumberOfSecondsUntil(this string start, string end)
    {
        return (int)(DateTime.Parse(end) - DateTime.Parse(start)).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

This can then be called like this:

```
int numSecs = startTime.NumberOfSecondsUntil(endTime);
```

YMMV :)